# Advice on Integrating Mediapipe into a Jetpack Compose Android App

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mediapipe

I am looking to make an android app that uses Mediapipe to use the handtracking software within it, using the Android camera. I have no issues working my way around Compose, but it seems that Mediapipe is not built with Compose in mind - even though that is Google's recommended way of building Android apps. I have posted a question on their Github page (no one has gotten back to me yet, but that's beside the issue).

My main question is: Has anyone accomplished getting Mediapipe into their app with Jetpack Compose? I've tried various different things but none of them seem to work at all, and I'm not at all good with using Views (it would also be difficult to transition the entire rest of my app all the way over to Views).

Secondary followup: if anyone has alternatives to Mediapipe that have worked with Jetpack Compose, I would appreciate that as well.

I have tried to manipulate Google's provided code to work with Jetpack Compose but nothing has worked. I have also tried to nest Views within my app based on a button press and then use Mediapipe from in there, but neither solution has worked and they seem sloppy to begin with.

Comment: May be of use: [Using TextureView and MediaPlayer in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090997/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang how exactly would this help? I don't understand the link exactly.

Comment: Compose is UI tool/framework but you are still dealing with Android Views and the rest of the Android framework. For example, Compose isn't directly involved with doing a connection to a webservice. I suspect that you want to render some Android View (perhaps camera, perhaps some other content) with Compose. The link shows a way to wrap that View inside Compose. A better question would be to show with code how you are trying integrate Compose and Mediapipe as right now any reader can't tell exactly what you are trying.